# Increasing mail size for postfix with amavisd-new and spamassassin

Tags: centos, email, postfix, spamassassin

I have a Centos 6 setup running a web and mail server. Email server works fine, however, my clients cannot send or receive emails with attachments size greater than 10MB.

I tried setting `mailbox_size_limit` and `message_size_limit` inside `/etc/postfix/main.cf` with no luck:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824
message_size_limit = 52428800
```

I searched on how to change mail size limit for **amavisd-new** and **spamassassin**, but couldn't find a working solution. How can I change the size limit for all the mails (body+attachments)? Also I can't see those rejects inside log files like `/var/log/maillog`. Is there any other log files I should be looking to check for mail rejects?

Also, can `dovecot`, IMAP and POP3 server, be related to this issue?

Comment: Care to look at the maillog and post the lines relevant to the rejected message with your question?

Comment: @the-wabbit thanks for the comment. As I already have stated in my question, I cannot find any message lines regarding these rejections inside `/var/log/maillog`. Is there any other file I should look inside for those rejects?

Comment: We don't do CentOS (much) over here, so I do not happen to have access to an actual CentOS system to check for the configuration of the syslog daemon, but do you have *anything meaningful* in *maillog*? Postfix is logging to the "mail" facility, even connection attempts are logged at the "INFO" level, so a rejection is certainly to appear in the logs as well if you find connection attempt log entries.

Comment: OK. I will grep some log files for the email addresses and I will update my question with everything I found.